# how to convert pdf files to jpg with soffice command?

Tags: cmd, openoffice.org

I've tried using  soffice -writer and swriter to convert pdf files to jpg:

[image: test]

The documentation is pretty rare and I can't seem to make it work. 
I'm sure something is happening because the OpenOficce icon shows up briefly but I don't know what because there is no trace of a new file...

I hope someone can help me...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This worked for me using LibreOffice 5:

```
for %F in (*.pdf) do "%ProgramFiles%\LibreOffice 5\program\soffice" -convert-to jpg "%F" -outdir conv
```

Explanation of the command:

- To convert more than one file, the [For](http://www.quepublishing.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1154761&seqNum=10) command specifies each name separately.
- `\conv` goes to `C:\conv`.  To put the folder on the desktop instead, just use `conv`.
- Use one dash rather than two on Windows.
- No need for the headless argument.

It did not work in Apache OpenOffice, apparently for several reasons:

- It had trouble reading the PDF.
- It expected the `conv` folder to already exist.
- Something seemed wrong with automatic conversion in general.  It opened the file but nothing happened.

Comment: Is there any possibility by which I can convert a multi page pdf file to an image.